# Is it possible to determine if a macro has been defined in a separate c file?

Tags: c, macros

I have two c files.  Without using any other files, is it possible to determine if a macro has been defined in c file one within c file two?  In a single c file this is possible via

```
#ifdef myMacro
```

I am writing a grading script and would like to be able to determine if a student has defined a specific macro within his/her submission.  Clearly, I could open the student .c file and iterate through it to see if it was defined.  However, I was wondering if there might be a more elegant solution.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. If it *were* possible, it would open some *very* strange behavior when something is first `#define`d and later `#undef`d in the other file.

Comment: Yea that's what I'm afraid of.  I might just have to bite the bullet.

Comment: You could generate a `c`  file that includes the student's `c` program (like `#include "student.c"`) and then check if the macro in question has been defined.

Comment: Why not just grep the file to see if the macro is defined?

Comment: @Tedford : `grep` may not understand the context of a define. For instance, if a student placed this in his code `#if 0` followed by `#define macroname` followed by `#endif` then the macro is not really defined but grep wouldn't know that.

Comment: @MichaelPetch for some reason I thought that wouldn't work, but it does lol.  If you add it as an answer I will accept it.  I've also up voted the other solution that doesn't use grep as it would also work.

Comment: If you wish to answer your own question with my suggestion (and it works for you), please feel free to do so. I only intended to provide a `drive by comment` before I went to the next question ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could generate a *C* file that includes the student's *C* program with something like

```
#include "student.c"
```

Your small *C* stub can then check if the macro in question has been defined or not. You could exit compilation with an error (or choose some other mechanism if the macro is defined):

```
#ifndef MACRONAME
# error "MACRONAME not defined"
#endif
```

You could then test for an error code from your compiler in a script. This method isn't entirely full proof. If the last statement of the student's code happens to be `#undef MACRONAME` then you won't detect that they may have defined the macro earlier in their code.

Answer (score 1):

A more elegant solution would be to just do it with a script, maybe a combination of `gcc -dM -E` only on the files submitted and then "`grep`ping" for the desired `#define`.

Answer (score 1):

i will suggest to create an include file that check for that eg:

```
-----------verify.h --------------
#ifndef MAGIC_MACRO
#error "MAGIC_MACRO is not defined"
#endif
--------------EOF --------------
```

and then insert a line as `#include "foldername/verify.h"` at the end of each *.c /*.cpp file

eg: in windows batch file

```
pushd [src path]
for /F "delims=|" %%i in ('dir /b /s *.c') do (
    echo.#include 'verify.h' >> %~dpnxi
)
popd
```

the compiler will generate an error on files where MAGIC_MACRO is not defined.

this is not the best solution but it works